# Union of two array, but time complexity is the issue

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, union, array-merge

Multiple solutions available online for union of arrays, I came up with one of my own which is working fine but again it has significant time complexities (which I obviously don't know). So in order to use similar logic in a better way I am asking here. Any suggestion would be great!

Initially there are two arrayList with different sizes and numbers in it.

1. First step is to append both of them in a single List
2. Second step is to sort the new array using **Collections.sort()**
   method.
3. Third is to use **.remove()** to remove the duplicates from it.
   Below is the code

*//initial two arrays*

array1[0, 2, 3, 4, 5] and array2[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]

*//for loop to append them in one arrayList and sort*

```
for(k = 0; k< array1.size();k++){
    array3.add(array1.get(k));
}
for(k = 0; k< array2.size();k++){
    array3.add(array2.get(k));
}
Collections.sort(array3);
```

*//Now removing the duplicates*

```
for(k=0; k<array3.size();k++){
    if(k != array3.size()-1){
       if(Objects.equals(array3.get(k), array3.get(k + 1))){
       array3.remove(k);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are the arrays sorted? From your example they certainly seem so

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention it

Comment: Your code impliest hat you are actually using `List` objects and not arrays. Calling them `array1` and so on will lead to quite some confusion.

Comment: Didn't follow the naming conventions here yet, focusing on just logic for now

Comment: Why don't you use a `Set`? A `Set` has the property of disallowing duplicate values.

Comment: Thanks, would definitely look into it @MCEmperor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [`IntStream.distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#distinct())

You can use `distinct()` operation, which maintains a `LinkedHashSet` under the hood to guarantee uniqueness of elements and preserve their order, to obtain the union of the given arrays:

```
int[] array1 = {0, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] array2 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8};
        
int[] union = IntStream
    .concat(Arrays.stream(array1), Arrays.stream(array2))
    .distinct().toArray();
        
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(union));
```

*Output:*

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this optimally via hash sets

```
int[] array1 = {0, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] array2 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8};
HashSet<Integer> union = new HashSet<>();

for (int element : array1) {
  union.add(element);
}

// Add all the elements of the second array to the HashSet
for (int element : array2) {
  union.add(element);
}
```

this solution does not guarantee the order of the elements in the union set.

Comment: "optimally" is a strong word. If the input is already sorted then simply iterating over both at the same time and picking the smaller one (and skipping any identical ones) will be faster.